# setting an image object on iframe using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I want to display an image in an iframe when I click that image inside that table. Problem is, the image that gets displayed inside the iframe is too small (too large images are not a problem for now). So I attempted to pass the image in a javascript function when it is clicked and perform the necessary resizes, but here I get another problem in setting the image object as the src of the iFrame. Any suggestions? Please guide me, I would save a lot of time if you can help.

Here is the javascript code I'm having problems with.

```
function resize(e){
    var newImg = document.createElement('img');
    newImg.src = document.getElementById(e).src; 
    newImg.width = '448'; 
    newImg.height = '336';
    document.getElementById('passTo').src = newImg.src; /*newImg doesn't work aswell*/
}
```

Here is my HTML code...

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="2" height="336">
    <iframe id = "passTo" name="A" src="Activity 6.html"  style="width:100%; height:100%;" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">
      <p>iframes are not supported by your browser.</p>
    </iframe>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><img src = "index.jpg" id = "myimg" border="3" height="48" width="64" onclick="resize(myimg)"></img></td>
  <td><img src = "index.jpg" id = "myimg2" border="3" height="48" width="64" onclick="resize(myimg2)"></img></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I strongly suggest you create an example at JSFiddle.net, that way it'll be a lot easier for people to debug it for you, you'll get more answers quicker.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest just setting the innerHTML of the iframe body:

```
function resize(e){
    var imgURL = document.getElementById(e).src;
    var iframe = document.getElementById('passTo');
    var html = "<img width='448' height='336' src=" + imgURL + ">";
    var doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
    doc.body.innerHTML = html;
}
```

Or, if you wanted to create the img object yourself and insert it, you could do it like this:

```
function resize(e){
    var imgURL = document.getElementById(e).src;
    var iframe = document.getElementById('passTo');
    // get iframe document in cross browser way
    var doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
    // create img object in the iframe's document.
    var img = doc.createElement("img");
    img.height = 336;
    img.width = 448;
    img.src = imgURL;
    doc.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

There were several issues with what you were previously trying:

1. You were settings the `iframe.src` to an image URL.  When doing that, you have no control over the `height` and `width` of the `img` object that the `iframe` creates and it has nothing to do with the other `img` object you had created.
2. You can't create an `img` object in one document and then use it in another document.

The easiest way to put some HTML in another document is be just setting HTML on it and letting the browser create the objects in the right document.

Also, keep in mind that you can only modify or read the DOM contents of an iframe if it's in the same domain as the window/frame your code is running in (which is OK in your example).